# I have 4 textviews which take their values from spinner. If TextView 3 and 4 are blank then I need to copy values from position 1 & 2

Tags: android

I have 4 textviews which take their values from dropdown list (spinner) selected at previous screen. 
There can be either 2 or 4 numbers/letters as result of this selection. 
The first position will always be a number and the second position will always be a letter. The third position can be a number or blank and the fourth position can be a letter or blank.
If position 3 and position 4 are blank then I need to make them equal to positions 1 & 2 respectively.

```
String myGrade = intent.getStringExtra("parameter_name_grade");

// above takes value of 'myGrade' from spinner selection at previous screen


    String mDisplayGradeNumberEff = (" " + myGrade.charAt(0));
    TextView displayGradeNumberEff = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gradeNumberEffTV);
    displayGradeNumberEff.setText(mDisplayGradeNumberEff);

    String mDisplayGradeLetterEff = (" " + myGrade.charAt(1));
    TextView displayGradeLetterEff = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gradeLetterEffTV);
    displayGradeLetterEff.setText(mDisplayGradeLetterEff);

    // above works correctly


    // from here down only works when a character is present in both positions
    // if positions 3(2) and 4(3) are empty app stops running.  

    String mDisplayGradeNumberDia = (" " + myGrade.charAt(2));  


    if (mDisplayGradeNumberDia.isEmpty()) {
        mDisplayGradeNumberDia = mDisplayGradeNumberEff;

    }

    TextView displayGradeNumberDia = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gradeNumberDiaTV);
    displayGradeNumberDia.setText(mDisplayGradeNumberDia);

    String mDisplayGradeLetterDia = (" " + myGrade.charAt(3));

    if (mDisplayGradeLetterDia.isEmpty()) {
        mDisplayGradeLetterDia = mDisplayGradeLetterEff;

    }

    TextView displayGradeLetterDia = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gradeLetterDiaTV);
    displayGradeLetterDia.setText(mDisplayGradeLetterDia);


}
```

Comment: Could you provide a Logcat?

Answer (score 0):

I Guess you have a array out of bounds exception, please provide Logcat....

Check if "myGrade" has 3/4 Characters, if it does not you can't read them with charAt(3)...

You can check the length of the String with "myGrade.length()"

Comment: I'm so new to this that I don't know how to send Logcat. If "myGrade" has 4 characters then it works fine, if it has 2 characters then it locks up.

Comment: Take a look at this to debug your code: http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-studio.html

Try to add  if (myGrade.length()>3){....}

Answer (score 0):

When I asked this question I was fairly new to the site and didn't understand that I should post back the solution for future reference. Solution below worked so thanks to rocket for your help and sorry for the delay!

```
    int myGradeLength = mGrade.length();

    if (myGradeLength != 4) {

        mDisplayGradeNumberEff = ("" + mGrade.charAt(0));
        mDisplayGradeLetterEff = ("" + mGrade.charAt(1));
        mDisplayGradeNumberDia = ("" + mGrade.charAt(0));
        mDisplayGradeLetterDia = ("" + mGrade.charAt(1));

    } else {

        mDisplayGradeNumberEff = ("" + mGrade.charAt(0));
        mDisplayGradeLetterEff = ("" + mGrade.charAt(1));
        mDisplayGradeNumberDia = ("" + mGrade.charAt(2));
        mDisplayGradeLetterDia = ("" + mGrade.charAt(3));
    }
```